# angular - upgrade from material 5 to material 7 without cli

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular7, npm-install

I have a complex Angular app, which is, among other things, a "hybrid" app running both Angular JS (1.6) and Angular (5.x).
Right now, I need to upgrade the Material version 5.2.4 to the latest (7.x).
I ran some installs on things that I found related to this purpose in the package.json file, but still things are not working correctly. I am getting this error, for example:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

This is coming from the "core.js" file, so I can't tell exactly where the problem is in the actual code.

I've ran the following command (**don't have CLI right now**):

```
npm i --save @angular/material@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/animations@latest @angular/cdk@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/common@latest
```

These installations themselves went through fine.

I cannot run this kind of update on ALL the packages I have in the app, as some of them cannot be updated right now, because of the nature of the app.

So, am I missing something here? Do I need to run an update on more (dependent) packages?

This is the entire packages list (including "dev"):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/upgrade": "5.2.8",
    "ag-grid": "17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "17.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "17.1.1",
    "angular": "1.6.7",
    "angular-animate": "1.6.7",
    "angular-aria": "1.6.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.2",
    "angular-daterangepicker": "0.2.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "2.5.0",
    "angular-immutable": "0.1.3",
    "angular-lz-string": "1.0.5",
    "angular-material": "1.1.8",
    "angular-material-data-table": "0.10.10",
    "angular-material-icons": "0.7.1",
    "angular-material-time-picker": "1.0.6",
    "angular-messages": "1.6.0",
    "angular-native-dragdrop": "1.2.2",
    "angular-post-message": "*",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.3",
    "angular-split": "1.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "0.4.8",
    "angular-timer": "1.3.3",
    "angular-toastr": "1.7.0",
    "angular-translate": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-local": "2.11.0",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.18",
    "angular-uuid": "0.0.4",
    "angulartics-piwik": "1.0.4",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "2.1.30",
    "bootstrap-material-design-icons": "2.2.0",
    "canvg-fixed": "1.0.0",
    "circular-json": "0.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "element-resize-detector": "1.1.14",
    "es6-collections": "0.5.6",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "filesize": "3.6.1",
    "fullcalendar": "2.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "howler": "^2.1.0",
    "html2canvas": "v1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "humanize-duration": "2.8.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "jqcloud2": "2.0.2",
    "jquery": "2.2.1",
    "jspdf": "1.3.5",
    "kendo-grid-editors": "1.1.2",
    "linqts": "1.8.3",
    "lodash": "4.12.0",
    "memoize-one": "4.0.3",
    "moment": "2.12.0",
    "ng-idle": "1.3.1",
    "ng-password-strength": "0.3.0",
    "ng-stomp": "0.4.0",
    "ng2-ion-range-slider": "2.0.0",
    "ngx-img-cropper": "0.10.4",
    "ngx-pipes": "2.1.2",
    "papaparse": "4.3.3",
    "post-robot": "8.0.15",
    "quill": "1.2.6",
    "reduce-reducers": "0.1.2",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "2.6.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "redux-undo": "1.0.0-beta9",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "shelljs": "0.6.0",
    "stompjs": "2.3.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.23",
    "tinymce": "4.7.10",
    "upath": "0.1.7",
    "zone.js": "0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.5",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.32",
    "@types/howler": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "8.10.15",
    "@types/webpack": "3.8.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.3",
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.1",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "body-parser": "1.15.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "clean-css": "4.0.7",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.17",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "connect-livereload": "0.5.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.8",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "dummy-json": "1.0.1",
    "es6-module-loader": "0.17.11",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.4",
    "flag-icon-css": "2.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.6.1",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "3.1.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "2.0.6",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-copy": "1.0.1",
    "gulp-intercept": "0.1.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "3.8.1",
    "gulp-prettify": "0.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.4.0",
    "gulp-replace": "0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "3.1.0",
    "gulp-war": "0.1.4",
    "gulp-watch-sass": "1.4.0",
    "gulp-zip": "4.0.0",
    "handlebars-loader": "1.6.0",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "0.12.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.4",
    "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "0.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.3",
    "increase-memory-limit": "1.0.6",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-matchers": "2.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.0.3",
    "karma-systemjs": "0.13.0",
    "livereload-js": "2.2.1",
    "mdi": "1.8.36",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "multer": "1.2.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.2",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "protractor": "5.3.0",
    "protractor-beautiful-reporter": "1.1.1",
    "protractor-flake": "3.0.2",
    "protractor-http-mock": "0.9.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
    "q": "1.4.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "request": "2.69.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "run-sequence": "2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "selfsigned": "1.10.1",
    "shelljs": "0.6.0",
    "socket.io": "1.4.6",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "system-text": "0.1.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.16.0",
    "systemjs-plugin-css": "0.1.32",
    "systemjs-plugin-json": "0.3.0",
    "through2": "2.0.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tree-kill": "1.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.3.7",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "typings": "1.3.x",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.6",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "uuid": "3.1.0",
    "vash": "0.11.3",
    "webpack": "3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.10.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "yargs": "6.6.0"
  }
```

If, eventually, this is a matter of things that are specific in this app, and can be only resolved within our dev team, that's an answer too, of course. I just want to make sure I am not missing something "globally known" here, before making this conclusion...

Comment: `still things are not working correctly`, what kind of things ?

Comment: @selemmn - you're right, didn't expand on this saying. edited the question now...

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade from one to an other Angular version, you should use their upgrade guide.

https://update.angular.io/

Select the current and new Angular version and be sure you put the App Complexity on Advanced, so you won't skip a step. You can use the checkboxes to validate if every step is done.

Be aware that it is advised to upgrade only one major version a time.

Last month I upgraded from angular 4 to 7 and this guide helped me a lot!

Comment: I wasn't aiming for upgrading the Angular itself in the app. As I've mentioned in the question, this is a hybrid app, running both Angular JS (1.6) and Angular (5). I am asking only about upgrading the Material package in this app - from version 5.2.4 (latest in 5.x) to version 7 (latest in 7.x)...

Comment: I would advise you to keep the angular (5) code version and the Angular Material version in sync. Different versions will result into problems. The support for angular 5 will also be dropped soon. https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the problem lies in the difference between the version of Angular (5) and the version of Material I was trying to install (7).
These versions should be in sync.